# Hive - Why does cast(col as timestamp) remove the millisecond digits if they are zero?

Tags: sql, string, datetime, hadoop, hive

I recently noticed the following issue with Hive but could not find a corresponding HIVE ticket, so would like to cross-check this.

I have a string type column which is actually a timestamp of the format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS. I am casting this column to a timestamp type as follows:

```
select my_str_col, cast(my_str_col as timestamp) as my_timestamp_col from my_table;
```

The results of the above query looks like this:
[image]

You can see that in the casted version, the last digits are ignored if any of them were 0. Why is this happening?

Comment: I observed the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a representation problem.

In a timestamp, just like in a number, a last decimal digit of value `0` is not meaningful; basically:

```
1.230 = 1.23
```

On the other hand, *string*-wise, every character matters, as well as the length of the string:

```
'1.230' <> '1.23'
```

Your datatype conversion works fine. Strings are turned to the relevant timestamp values. It is just the representation of the two datatypes that makes it look like they are different.